# Howto extract all request headers in Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping

I    am    not    able    to    get    all    the    cookies    passes    in request    headers    in    scrapy   ?

How    can    i    get    **all**    the       cookies    of    request    header?

Comment: I used both response.headers.getlist('set-cookie') as well as response.request.headers() methods

Comment: yes its nice and more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Set **COOKIES_ENABLED = True, COOKIES_DEBUG = True** in your settings file and try **response.headers.getlist('set-cookie')**

Comment: I did that too but i am not getting all the cookies passed in request header